# Converting docx/ODT to image using Java

Tags: java, image, converters, odt

I am working on a Spring REST service based web application (UI is based on HTML5, backbone.js). The actual requirement is, an uploaded document (could be any document like excel, word, ppt, pdf etc) requires an preview option using which an user can view the document in the browser (user may or may not have office installed).

My idea is to convert the documents into images and display them to the user. On searching, i found multiple ways to convert a PDF to image but not much ODT to image (Note: I am looking for an open source). JODConverter, docx4j can be used to convert the documents to pdf. Then I can convert these PDFs to images. But is this the right way. Is there any other efficient way to achieve the same. Please suggest and point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance.
Gopi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you won't do any better than `.docx` to `.pdf` to image. You really need a stable workflow, and this is as good as you'll find for this purpose, unless you're running on a Microsoft server and you have access to the official Microsoft Office stuff.

For previews, docx4j or similar will do just fine. Not everything converts perfectly, but it should be fine for a preview.